# How to clear or change the text of an input field when I select an option value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this HTML5 code:

```
<select id="#list">
<option data-value="1" class="option">Red</option>
<option data-value="2" class="option">Green</option>
<option data-value="3" class="option">Blue</option>
<option data-value="4" class="option">Orange</option>
</select>
```

and with the code below i m trying to clear the default value of the input field when I select the "Orange" option from the drop-down list.

```
$("#list").on("change", function () {
 if(this.value === "Orange") {
 $('#price').val('');
}
});
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work ! What am I missing??

[**JSFiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/vp0ggxnm/1/)

Comment: First: Change `<select id="#list">` to `<select id="list">`.

Comment: Oh my !!! I m sooo stupid !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** or **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** jQuery method to extract `data-*` value.

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
// A range of prices
var priceIndex = [2.26, 5.5, 10, 20.01];

// change event on select#list...
$("#list").on("change", function() {

  /* Get value from data-* attribute with data()
  || method and store the value of the selected
  || option.option in a variable
  */
  var val = $(this).find('option:selected').data('value');
  
  // Determine the price by matching val to index
  var v = priceIndex[val-1];
  
  // Format price
  var price = currency(v, 'us');
  
  // Display value in output#price
  $('#price').val('$'+price);

});

// Utility to format currency
function currency(number, country) {
    return (number).toLocaleString(country, {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
    });
}
```

```html
<select id="list">
<option default></option>
<option data-value="1" class="option">Red</option>
<option data-value="2" class="option">Green</option>
<option data-value="3" class="option">Blue</option>
<option data-value="4" class="option">Orange</option>
</select>

<label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<output id="price">0</output></label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list").on("change", function() {
  var dataSelect = $("#list option:selected").attr('data-value');
  if(dataSelect == '4') $('#price').html('');
});
```

[Online test](http://jsbin.com/nunimozeju/edit?html,js,console,output)